# Is it possible to show HWND->i in MessageBox()?

Tags: c++, winapi, hwnd

I'm using the following code to get `HWND->i` but when I start the program it terminates with dialog box "Program.exe has encountered a problem and needs to close":

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <sstream>

LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc (HWND, UINT, WPARAM, LPARAM) ;

int WINAPI WinMain (HINSTANCE hInstance, HINSTANCE hPrevInstance,
                    PSTR szCmdLine, int iCmdShow)
{
     static TCHAR szAppName[] = TEXT ("Program") ;
     HWND         hwnd ;
     MSG          msg ;
     WNDCLASS     wndclass ;

     wndclass.style         = CS_HREDRAW | CS_VREDRAW ;
     wndclass.lpfnWndProc   = WndProc ;
     wndclass.cbClsExtra    = 0 ;
     wndclass.cbWndExtra    = 0 ;
     wndclass.hInstance     = hInstance ;
     wndclass.hIcon         = LoadIcon (NULL, IDI_APPLICATION) ;
     wndclass.hCursor       = LoadCursor (NULL, IDC_ARROW) ;
     wndclass.hbrBackground = (HBRUSH) GetStockObject (WHITE_BRUSH) ;
     wndclass.lpszMenuName  = NULL ;
     wndclass.lpszClassName = szAppName ;

     if (!RegisterClass (&wndclass))
     {
          MessageBox (NULL, TEXT ("Error"), szAppName, MB_ICONERROR) ;
          return 0 ;
     }
     hwnd = CreateWindow (szAppName,
                          TEXT ("Program"),
                          WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW,
                          CW_USEDEFAULT,
                          CW_USEDEFAULT,
                          CW_USEDEFAULT,
                          CW_USEDEFAULT,
                          NULL,
                          NULL,
                          hInstance,
                          NULL) ;

     ShowWindow (hwnd, iCmdShow) ;

     std::ostringstream oss;
     oss << hwnd->i;
     //MessageBox(NULL, oss.str().c_str(), TEXT("message"), MB_OK);

     while (GetMessage (&msg, NULL, 0, 0))
     {
          TranslateMessage (&msg) ;
          DispatchMessage (&msg) ;
     }
     return msg.wParam ;
}

LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc (HWND hwnd, UINT message, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
     switch (message)
     {
     case WM_DESTROY:
          PostQuitMessage (0) ;
          return 0 ;
     }
     return DefWindowProc (hwnd, message, wParam, lParam) ;
}
```

When I comment out

```
oss << hwnd->i;
```

the program runs normally.

So, is there a way to show `hwnd->i` in `MessageBox()`?

Comment: `HWND` is an opaque pointer to you, I it's not normally dereferenced by the user.

Comment: Can you explain where you got the idea that a `HWND` points to a structure that has a member `i`?

Comment: @Kaz It's in include\windef.h of MinGW installation folder. There's a macro `DECLARE_HANDLE(HWND);` that expands to `typedef struct HWND__{int i;}*HWND`. The `DECLARE_HANDLE()` macro is in include\winnt.h.

Comment: @user1257 LOL; this is obviously just a dummy, and not the real structure.  (I have no idea why, if they wanted type checking, they didn't just use an incomplete struct type like `typedef struct HWND__ *HWND`.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As it says in [MSDN here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ff381403%28v=vs.85%29.aspx):

> Windows are objects — they have both code and data — but they are not
>   C++ classes. Instead, a program references a window by using a value
>   called a handle. A handle is an opaque type. Essentially, it is just a
>   number that the operating system uses to identify an object. You can
>   picture Windows as having a big table of all the windows that have
>   been created. It uses this table to look up windows by their handles.
>   (Whether that's exactly how it works internally is not important.) The
>   data type for window handles is HWND, which is usually pronounced
>   "aitch-wind." Window handles are returned by the functions that create
>   windows: **CreateWindow** and **CreateWindowEx**.

And crucially, this comment:

> Keep in mind that handles are not pointers. If hwnd is a variable that
>   contains a handle, attempting to dereference the handle by writing
>   *hwnd is an error.

The main point is that an `HWND` is only something you pass along to API calls that deal with windows. Its internal implementation is hidden and is of no concern to developers. By calling `HWND->i`, you are attempting to dereference it as if it were a pointer, which it's not. Therefore you crash.

Answer (score 1):

Others have explained why dereferencing an `HWND` crashes (it does not point to memory that the app owns), but noone has explained why the compiler would accept `HWND->...` syntax to being with.

It is to facilitate [`STRICT` type checking](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa383732%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) at compile-time:

> When `STRICT` is defined, data type definitions
>   change as follows:
>
> - Specific handle types are defined to be mutually
>     exclusive; for example, you will not be able to pass
>     an `HWND` where an `HDC` type argument is
>     required. Without `STRICT`, all handles are defined
>     as integers, so the compiler does not prevent you
>     from using one type of handle where another type is
>     expected.

When `STRICT` is not defined, `HWND` is defined as an untyped pointer:

```
typedef void *HANDLE;
typedef HANDLE HWND;
```

Thus `HWND->...` is invalid at compile-time since `void` has no members.  However, when `STRICT` is defined, `HWND` is defined as a pointer to a `struct` instead:

```
struct HWND__ { int unused; };
typedef struct HWND__ *HWND;
```

Thus `HWND->...` is accepted at compile-time because `HWND__` has a member, but fails at run-time since an `HWND` does not actually point at a valid `HWND__` instance.

As for why `->i` specifically compiles, your copy of the Windows SDK headers likely defines the `unused` member as `i` instead (which apparently MinGW does, for instance). Otherwise, you should have gotten a compiler error about `i` being an unknown member.

Comment: Now that *is* interesting - many thanks! +1 for illumination :-)

Answer (score 0):

HWND itself repesents a window, and the internal structure it looks to refer is there only as a placeholder.

In fact it is an index used by the windows API to map the data that leave into the window manager, outside your process, that are even not visible to you.

The address it apparently points to does not belong to your program (and may even not be an address) and hence accessing `hwnd->i` is undefined behavior: if you are lucky the program crashes (thus revealing the error) otherwise it will access random data.